# Bootstrap 4 - Creating centered and equal width flex items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm new to bootstrap still. From what I can tell in terms of layout, you can go with two main options: flex or grid. I'm currently attempting to go with the flexbox method, however I've encountered a problem with width.

My goal is to create three rows (the code I've attached only has 1 row for simplicity) that each have two equal width boxes per row. One box will have a picture and the other box will have text. I also want these boxes to be responsive, so that when the screen is small the boxes stack on top of each other (1 by 1). My only guess for the responsive part is that I use d-md-flex. Here's what I have so far:

```
        <!--Row 1-->
        <div class="d-flex flex-column mb-3 text-white">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="text-center"><img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/Whole_Stadium.JPG" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                <div class="text-center"><p class="m-0">INTRODUCTION: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac rhoncus sem. Vestibulum consectetur
                    arcu est, at malesuada dolor posuere in. Cras tincidunt est eget ullamcorper mattis. Sed interdum ultricies venenatis. Nam
                    nunc neque, imperdiet vitae auctor sed, rhoncus quis enim. Maecenas sit amet purus aliquet, gravida purus sit amet, maximus
                    ligula. Praesent ut enim arcu. Nunc sit amet orci velit. Sed blandit consectetur suscipit. Vestibulum interdum pharetra
                    elit, nec pharetra arcu pretium quis. In vel sapien felis.</p></div>
            </div>
```

My problem is that the image turns out really small and to the left, while the text takes up most of the space on the row. I've attempted playing around with flex-grow/shrink and flex-fill however nothing was changed. Any suggestions (on that and the responsiveness if its not too much to ask)?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what *didn't* work before we head of on tangents. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: Like I said after the code, I attempted using flex-grow on the two flex items within the row. It didn't fix their width

Comment: In scenarios like this I have found bootstrap grid as a better solution from my experience. Although .flex-fill claims equal width items it happens to be dependent on content of the flex item.

Comment: so is there no way to do it with flex then?

Comment: May be by adding flex properties to your css classes. Below I have posted a code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
            .parent {
            display : flex;
            border  : solid 1px;
            }

            .child {
            flex : 1;
            }
```

```html
            <head>
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                </head>
                <div>Using Flex</div>
                            <div class="parent">
                                <div class="child bg-info"><img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/Whole_Stadium.JPG" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                                <div class="child bg-warning"><p class="m-0">INTRODUCTION: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac rhoncus sem. Vestibulum consectetur
                                    arcu est, at malesuada dolor posuere in. Cras tincidunt est eget ullamcorper mattis. Sed interdum ultricies venenatis. Nam
                                    nunc neque, imperdiet vitae auctor sed, rhoncus quis enim. Maecenas sit amet purus aliquet, gravida purus sit amet, maximus
                                    ligula. Praesent ut enim arcu. Nunc sit amet orci velit. Sed blandit consectetur suscipit. Vestibulum interdum pharetra
                                    elit, nec pharetra arcu pretium quis. In vel sapien felis.</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="parent">
                                <div class="child bg-info"><img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/Whole_Stadium.JPG" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                                <div class="child bg-warning"><p class="m-0">Row 2</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="parent">
                                <div class="child bg-info"><img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/Whole_Stadium.JPG" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                                <div class="child bg-warning"><p class="m-0">Row 3</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div>Using Grid</div>
                                                <div class="row border border-dark">
                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 bg-info"><img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/Whole_Stadium.JPG" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 bg-warning"><p class="m-0">INTRODUCTION: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac rhoncus sem. Vestibulum consectetur
                                    arcu est, at malesuada dolor posuere in. Cras tincidunt est eget ullamcorper mattis. Sed interdum ultricies venenatis. Nam
                                    nunc neque, imperdiet vitae auctor sed, rhoncus quis enim. Maecenas sit amet purus aliquet, gravida purus sit amet, maximus
                                    ligula. Praesent ut enim arcu. Nunc sit amet orci velit. Sed blandit consectetur suscipit. Vestibulum interdum pharetra
                                    elit, nec pharetra arcu pretium quis. In vel sapien felis.</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row border border-dark">
                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 bg-info"><img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/Whole_Stadium.JPG" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 bg-warning"><p class="m-0">Row 2</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row border border-dark">
                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 bg-info"><img src="Photos/2019 SB Photos/Whole_Stadium.JPG" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 bg-warning"><p class="m-0">Row 3</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Ok this is perfect. Is it possible to do this with bootstrap?

Comment: if interested you can try bootstrap grid.

Comment: Updated code snippet to show how to use both flex features and bootstrap grid. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

If you want three rows, you need to use `display: flex;` as well as `flex-direction: column;` if you use 3 items they will stand up and the first will be on top, the second after, the third on bottom. if you want to make it any more complex, instead of stacking 3 elements, you can stack 3  more flex boxes, then organize the info from there.

check this out
https://www.steveaolsen.com/docs/FlexboxCheatsheet.pdf
let me know if that helps!

i used this sheet every time i'm working in CSS and its a life saver

Comment: I think the problem is not about creating rows. Its about items with in a row. Each row has two flex items with varying content. And flexbox seems to auto allocate width based on content size of flex items. Using flex-fill also doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can declare width for flex children. you can also use the wrap options. you can also use float inside flex items. OP give us the entire code and we'll figure it out

Comment: Yes agreed, I have posted something similar above using flex with in our css classes, meaning there is not a direct flexbox css class(like col-* in grid) available that can be used directly on div in this case!?